# Allow PR Build Validation builds without publishing artifacts

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to set up some build validation for PR's on our master branch (We're using Git and VSTS). I added some build policies to kick off various builds depending on what files have changed. For some background, we create PR's somewhat early in the process so we can track changes and add comments as our feature branch is developed.

Now, I want these builds to run and succeed in order for a PR to be completed, however, I don't want the output (artifacts) from these builds to be published. Our publishes look at the latest build artifact to deploy, and in this case, the latest build artifact would be from the PR. If we did allow these build artifacts from the PR to be published, then we'd be publishing feature branch code (which came from the PR) to our main site, which isn't desirable (we have a separate publish to handle our feature branch sites).

Essentially, when doing a PR, I just want to run the build to make sure that everything is kosher, and then throw away the build once it's completed.

Outside of creating a build definition solely for PR validation, I'm not sure what I can do. I've googled and asked around, but I'm either not asking the right questions, or the answer isn't as simple as I hope.

Hopefully I've included enough details to explain my problem.

### TL;DR

How can I run build validations on a PR without having a publish pick up and deploy the build artifact that resulted from the validation build?

### Edit (More details)

I tried adding conditions to the publish task (also tried putting the publish in a phase and conditionally running that). However, when I go to make a new release, it still sees the build definition that was run. Now, I imagine that if I tried to release that build definition, it would fail because no artifact was created. But I don't even want to see that build definition when I'm doing a release (don't want to accidentally select it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the Publish Artifact task its own Phase at the end of your build definition then use 'Run this phase' with 'Custom condition using variable expressions'. You can also do this at the Task level as Dan suggested in the comment below.

```html
not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts

Comment: Why not just put the condition on the tasks themselves instead of creating a whole separate phase for it?

Comment: Oh that would work too, I didn't realized variable expressions could be used at the task level.

Comment: Tried that, and it works for not creating an artifact, but the publish still sees a build definition to use. Edited question to represent this.

Comment: What do you mean the publish artifact still sees a build definition to use? The publish artifact task is part of the build definition. Do you mean a release?

Comment: Sorry, my terminology is probably off. Yes, when I'm making a new release, it still sees that build definition.

Comment: If you don't want your release definition to see it, you can go with option 1 and have your release definition only consume your original Build Definition. Another option would be to use tags and the 'Artifact Filters' under release triggers.

Comment: Build tags and artifact filters was best solution to our problem (since we are trying to avoid creating builds just for PR's). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andrew How did you managed to do it? Any tutorials I can follow up?

Comment: @PedroFaustino, what we ended up doing was using a powershell task that looked at the $env:BUILD_REASON and added some variables that were then used to optionally publish the build artifact. Further, we used a naming scheme that excluded PR builds from being a default option for releases. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've achieved a similar process by adding a build branch filter on the continuous deployment trigger. When the PR build validation occurs, Azure creates a specific branch that represents the PR merged with the target branch (e.g. develop). Once we approve the PR, the build will occur on the develop branch, so by setting a filter that indicates that only builds on the develop branch will deploy a release, we can exclude the PR build validations.

Comment: @Andrew Did you try the option Default Version value to "Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags" by selecting artifact in release pipeline? It will select artifacts created by default branch and all other artifacts ignored when creating release

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple options you can follow to skip publishing artifacts for PR build validation.

#### Option 1: use a separate build definition for PR build validation

You can **clone the current build definition**, and use the cloned build definition for PR build validation separately.

[image]

In the cloned build definition, you can remove the tasks you do not want PR build validation execute (such as remove Publish Build Artifacts task).

#### Option 2: use customer condition to skip executing Publish Build Artifacts task

Or you can use [**custom conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts) for the tasks you want to run conditionally (as Calidus and Daniel mentions).

Such as add below custom condition for Publish Build Artifacts task (if the build is for PR validation, then not execute the task):

```
ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

[image]

Comment: Tried option 2, and it works for not creating an artifact, but the publish still sees a build definition to use. Edited question to represent this. I'd like to avoid making a new build definition just for merges.

Comment: Is there any way for option 1 not to run both build definitions when the PR gets merged to the target branch?