# Azure DevOps how to skip PublishBuildArtifacts step for PR build runs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Azure DevOps and I have a single build pipeline with a number of steps including `PublishBuildArtifacts` defined in the `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

I have pointed the same pipeline for the Build Validation (Validate code by pre-merging and building pull request changes.) from the master branch's build policies option. However, for this PR build run, I don't to run certain tasks like `PublishBuildArtifacts`.

How can I achieve this? I can think of one way which is to create a separate pipeline for PR and also a separate `azure-pipelines-pr.yml` file and not adding those tasks in that file. But this feels like an approach with redundancy to me. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow PR Build Validation builds without publishing artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845698/allow-pr-build-validation-builds-without-publishing-artifacts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [a custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the publish artifacts step:

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Now the step will run only when the build reason is **not** pull request.